# Objective C: Errors when initializing my constructor

Tags: objective-c, constructor, initialization

Pretty new to Objective C - Working on constructors right now, and am unable to do it without errors. I think I have the everything down, except initialization. Thanks for looking.

The errors that I'm getting :

> 1. main.m: In function -[Person initWithInfo:weight:gender:]:
>      main.m:46:9: error: print undeclared (first use in this function) 
>      -(void) print {
>           ^
> 2. main.m:46:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once
>      for each function it appears in main.m:46:15: error: expected ; before
>      { token
>      -(void) print {
> 3. main.m:85:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input 
>      }

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject {

int age, weight;
NSMutableString * gender;

}

-(id) initWithInfo : (int) a
weight: (int) w
gender: (NSString *) s;

-(void) print;

-(void) setAge : (int) a;
-(void) setWeight : (int) w;
-(void) setGender : (NSString *) s;

-(int) getAge;
-(int) getWeight;
-(NSString *) getGender;

@end

@implementation Person

-(id) initWithInfo : (int) a
weight: (int) w
gender: (NSString *) s{

self = [super init];

if (self)
{
self.weight = w;
self.age = a;
self.gender = s;

}

return self;


-(void) print {
NSLog(@"You are %d years old, weight %d pounds, and are a %@.", age, weight, gender);
}

-(void) setAge : (int) a{
age = a;
}
-(void) setWeight : (int) w{
weight = w;
}
-(void) setGender : (NSString *) s{
gender = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString : s];
}

-(int) getAge{return age;}
-(int) getWeight{return weight;}
-(NSString *) getGender{return gender;}

@end

int main(){

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

Person * Leo = 

[ [Person alloc] 

initWithInfo : 28
weight: 200
gender: @"Male"];

//[Leo print];


[pool drain];

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing a closing bracket after your

```
-(id) initWithInfo : (int) a 
weight: (int) w
gender: (NSString *) s{
```

function. You have

```
return self;
```

and then no closing bracket. Put a "}" there and that should do it.

Comment: Wow, that was a bad mistake by me! Thanks for catching it!